# Why do C++ constructors require default parameters in inheritance?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

The compiler gives me an error, when I haven't provided any default parameters in the constructor, stating that I need to provide them. I've tried two different cases:

1. Providing a default parameter to x(x = 0) and none to the name in the derived class gives me an error
2. Providing a default parameter to name and not to x in the derived class compiles perfectly fine.
   I don't understand what's going on because in the base class, whether default parameters have been provided or not doesn't really change anything. Is this only specific to derived classes? Why does providing a default argument to one parameter require a default argument for the other, or is this only for inherited variables?

```
//Inheritance
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
//why do constructors require default parameters

class Person
{
private:

public:
    string name;
    Person(string ref = " ")
        :name{ref}
    {
    }

    string Name()
    {
        return name;
    }
};

class Agent : public Person
{
private:

public:
    int kills;
    Agent(int x , string name = " " )   : kills{ x }, Person{name}
    {

    }
    void Detail()
    {
        cout << "Name : " << name << endl;
        cout << "Kills : " << kills << endl;
    }

};

int main()
{
    Agent test(24, "James bond");
    test.Detail();
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you for the help

Comment: Can you show an example of the code that *doesn't* compile?

Comment: It looks like your code compiles. Can you give us an example of the code that was failing and can you [edit] the error message into your question?

Comment: Inherited classes should be before class members in the member initializer list.

Comment: https://tio.run/##hVLLTsQwDLz7K6xyaaWFIsSpXSEhcQEkxC9kU@9uRDYpeSygqt9e4j5EEQd8SNrxeDy2Itv28iDlMJTlozmSU0EYSXChjNSxoa2yPjgSpzuA6JU5oBEn8q2QhD40NZTlx/ELG4vSmsSMMljn0dF7VI6wob2IOmArXCoL5DyA1MJ7fE3f1kAHrVNnEagCaONOK1kBpkhSS7N6BCZ@PuOO9sUIc1TM6hLUj1A3nj2sdV4SIy9WaQ5HITqz6tFDXy/@7g9kAlY4mfrPrkrcN6W1n4TG4pzBT9ysZynY7sTsUq7fzMIdJxf7sxc@z1Y1@EBBKP3HvrQx4HaLGQ@XVDP@YR2@yTS6/kt95s4Ld7Txm5y2xitg5yehTOrZ/QyEgXzIb243mD3xI8CdNU1WTJWcu1qcTtC83@sa@mH4Bg

Comment: The question does not says that the code doesn't compile.  It says that it doesn't compile when there is no default argument. So the question seems acceptable and  Jesper could even provide a relevant answer.  I therefore propose to reopen it.

Comment: @Christophe but it **does compile** in either cases. [see](https://godbolt.org/z/Bs5M9S)

Comment: @Christophe I agree and also voted to reopen.

Answer (score 5):

Constructors don't *require* default arguments at all. Only if you want them to be usable as default constructors.

If a class has no default constructor you can still use it as a base class. You just have to call the correct constructor yourself in derived class constructors (in the initialization list - you initialize base classes first, your own members second)

For example

```
struct a { int m_i; a(int i) : m_i(i) {} };
struct b : a { int my_i; b() : a(42), my_i(666) {} };
```